# Chamando Função na View - Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel-5

Galera, faz um tempinho que não programo PHP e estou com a seguinte duvida:

Estou chamando uma função na minha View da seguinte forma:

```
{{ $result_resumo = app(App\Http\Controllers\Site\SiteController::class)->NoticiasResumo($dados_noticias->post,80, FALSE, "") }}
```

Agora eu pergunto:

Existe outra forma de chamar a função sem a necessidade de digitar o caminho todo do `Controller`?

Observação: Estou usando a Framework Laravel 5.5

Comment: Seguinte, não tem necessidade de ser assim, o que o método faz? Não é bom instanciar um `controller` dessa maneira. Pergunto o que você deseja fazer? coloque todo os pontos.

Comment: esse método formata o texto para eu exibir um resumo de noticias formatado, ele retira tags html, etc etc ... estou chamando ele dessa forma.... Qual a melhor forma de chamar esse método na view?

Comment: Fazer um helper (ou função, `function`) ou até um pacote de utilidades e chamar o código no seu controller enviando para `view` somente o resultado. Não pode instânciar `Controller` diretamente na `View`.

Comment: Isso vai meio que contra o conceito do MVC não? Que tal já enviar os dados formatados quando chama a view no controller? Assim só teria o trabalho de imprimir a variavel passada pro blade...(como o Virgilio disse)